# Embedding Ruby in C++ missing "class" method

Tags: c++, ruby, embedded-ruby

I'd like to ask for your help on an issue when embedding ruby in C++.
I am upgrading from an older version of ruby to version 3.2. Previously, I could call ruby_init and ruby_init_loadpath as usual and then things would work, but now I need to call ruby_executable_node before calling ruby_init_loadpath.

Something like this (the parameters to ruby are arbitrary):

```
char* opt[] = { "ruby", "-v", "-eputs 'Starting'" };
int status;
ruby_executable_node(ruby_options(3, opt), &status);
```

This doesn't seem like the right thing to do, but unless I do this, all of my ruby objects are missing the class method (the error is undefined method `class'). I went through the changelogs for ruby, but couldn't find anything related to this change.
Does anyone know why this happens, or if there is a workaround?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this example](http://silverhammermba.github.io/emberb/embed/), you can pass the argument `"-e "` to have Ruby execute no code while passing options. It sounds like that works around your issue.

Comment: Hello Max, thank you very much for the link. I tried passing "-e " and it worked, (i.e., I get the same result as before), but still not sure why ruby_executable_node and ruby_options need to be called. Is there some additional intialisation being done when these are called? I saw ruby_init_stack is called in ruby_options, but I am calling this before ruby_init (through the RUBY_INIT_STACK macro). Another thing I noticed in the example is the call to ruby_exec_node, but actually even without calling this my ruby code is executed.

Comment: @nyangostar that's a good question and I don't know. I created the site I linked to in my answer and as you can see there it definitely used to work if you just call `ruby_init`. I logged a bug for myself to look into it https://github.com/silverhammermba/emberb/issues/27 let me know if you figure anything out!

Comment: Ah, this was your guide! Thank you very much for the guide! Sure, I will update here if I find anything.